# Cortana stops listening after a few words

Tags: cortana

I just upgraded to Windows 10 on my laptop.  When I ask Cortana a question, it appears "she" only hears the first few seconds of what I say.  I have checked audio settings and done the mic configuration wizard.  When I have to read the sentence about Peter during configuration, it hears everything I say, so I can almost rule out an issue with my laptop.

Examples:

- I asked "What time does Lowe's close tonight?"
- She heard "What time does low" then said "Something's not right"
- I asked "How do I get to Charlottesville Virginia"
- She heard "How do I get to Charlotte" then said "Something went
  wrong, try again in a little bit"

This same sort of pattern happened with every question I asked.  Surely she is supposed to hear more than just a few seconds.  What could the problem be?

Comment: I presume you have a supported microphone?

Comment: What are you classifying as a "supported microphone"?

Comment: When you setup cortana dos it complain about your microphone?

Comment: It does say that the mic "may not work" with Cortana, then it lets you do the configuration, and when I read the words it seems to pick everything up fine, and doesn't appear to cut out halfway through.  The issue just seems like a very specific one for it to just be a mic problem.  Besides, a mic is a mic, how complicated can it be  :)

Comment: It is Microsoft.  You would think s microphone is microphone but we were both told our microphone was special enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using a high quality microphone may help. Cortana does have problems with speech recognition. Check here: https://cortana.uservoice.com/forums/249009-general-cortana-feedback/suggestions/6792406-voice-recognition-sucks-ass

I was so excited to use it and upgraded my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 but Cortana is flop and over-hyped by media. I found an [alternative assistant named Braina](http://www.brainasoft.com/braina/cortana-for-pc.html). It has a plain interface but has great features and has been quite useful so far.